# How to remove report blind text from a generated pdf

Tags: pdftex, pdf, pylatex

I have manages to generate a pdf using latex and faced a problem of getting unnecessary text in my pdf as attached below. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
[image]

My tex file starts as below

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{heuristica} 
\usepackage[heuristica,vvarbb,bigdelims]{newtxmath} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\textosf{#1}} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3} 
\usepackage[a4paper,% 
left=0.7in,right=0.7in,top=0.9in,bottom=0.9in,% 
footskip=.25in]{geometry} 


\begin{document}
```

My code is as below

```
from pylatex import Document, Section, Subsection, Command, Figure, SubFigure, Package
from pylatex.utils import italic, NoEscape

latex_document = '120.tex'
with open(latex_document) as file:
    tex= file.read()

doc = Document('basic')
doc.append(NoEscape(tex))
doc.packages.append(Package('graphicx'))
doc.generate_pdf(clean_tex=False)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
Thanks..!

Comment: Did you get any error messages upon compiling your document? If so, which? Please also prepare a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we do not want to use

```
\begin{document}
```

in the .tex file, since it will be automatically append when the .tex file is appending to the doc file. after removing \begin{document} and its closing line, the issue got fixed